# loop over js array in d3 callback tree

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I would like to construct an SVG using d3 and the typical workflow is

```js
    const g = this.svg.selectAll("g").data()
    .enter()
    .call(el => el.append("g")
      .attr("class", d => "color" + d.data.color)
      .call(el => el.append("title")
        .text(d => d.data.text)
      )
      .call(el => el.append("text")
        .attr("y", d => y(d.y0 + d.y1)/2)
        .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .attr("clip-path", d => "url(#" + "cp" + d.id + ")")
        .call(el => // ...
```

The `d.data` object contains all the info, and amongst which is an *array* of strings. I would  like to loop over the array and `el.append` the items as `"text"` elements. I do not know how to access `d.data`, though, unless in an `attr`.

Any hints?

Comment: This is definitely **not** the *"typical workflow"* when it comes to D3! An idiomatic D3-*ish* approach should be feasible without any use of `.call()`. There is no need to *loop over the array* to append your texts. The magic of D3's data binding and data joins will do the trick. Please try to set up a [mcve] including an excerpt of your data structure. That will most likely yield multiple solutions to your problem very soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to be overly using `call` to access properties that you should just access directly. You are using a workaround where you can append properties to new properties, but the most common pattern is the following. See also [this showcase](https://observablehq.com/@dnarvaez27/understanding-enter-exit-merge-key-function).

```
// First, create a selection using `selectAll`
// and assign the new data object
let g = this.svg.selectAll("g").data(myDataObj);
// Exit old elements
g.exit().remove();

// Then, take the `.enter()` selection, and apply
// all the operations you only want to perform once
// like appending and setting static (data agnostic) variables
const gEnter = g.enter()
    .append("g");
gEnter.append("title");

// And then to do stuff for old *and* new `g`, using
// `.merge()` to merge the `.enter()` and `update` selections
// together
g = gEnter.merge(g)
    .attr("class", d => "color" + d.data.color);
g.select("title")
    .text(d => d.data.text);


// Now, for the `text` nodes, repeat the steps
// By passing a function to data, you perform a `Array#map`-like
// operation where the argument is the parent `datum` object and
// `data` is the result of the function
const text = g.selectAll("text").datum(d => d.data.text);

// First apply the constant attributes only once
text.enter()
    .append("text")
    .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle")
    .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
    // Now we apply stuff to both the new and the old elements
    .merge(text)
    .attr("y", d => y(d.y0 + d.y1)/2)
    .attr("clip-path", d => "url(#" + "cp" + d.id + ")")
    .text(d => d);
```

I don't know your exact data format, but I presume `d.id`, `d.y0` and `d.y1` are not attributes of the original `d`, but of `d.data.text`, because otherwise they wouldn't be unique. If they are properties of the original object, I recommend that you use [`.each()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-selection/#selection_each) instead of `.call()`, so you have access to the datum object:

```
// Use function so `this` points to the current SVGGElement node
g.each(function(e, j) {
    const text = g.selectAll("text").datum(e.data.text);
    text.enter()
        .append("text")
        .attr("alignment-baseline", "middle")
        .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
        .merge(text)
        .attr("y", d => y(e.y0 + e.y1)/2)
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#" + "cp" + e.id + ")")
        .text(d => d);
});
```